# is it possible to replace the default console in eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, cmd, eclipse-cdt

I would like to know whether it is possible to replace the default console in Eclipse CDT.

Is it possible to change in such a way that when we run the program from Eclipse the `.exe`-file should run in the `cmd.exe` console, not the Eclipse console like in Visual Studio.

I have checked the Internet and found that by changing **"external tools configuration"** it is possible to start the cmd.exe inside the Eclipse but I have to manually type the executable name in the command prompt. Giving the executable name as arguments under **"external tools configuration"** also do not work.

Is there a way to run the executable automatically?

Comment: May I know the reason when you want to use an external console instead of the internal?

Answer (score 0):

The reason i want to replace the default eclipse console is that it is not behaving properly while running a console application using scanf(),printf() statements.

for eg

```
main()
    {
       printf("enter a number");
       scanf("%d",&number);
       printf("number is %d",number);
     }
```

would result in the following output on eclipse console

```
1
enter a number number is 1
```

the first  `printf("enter a number");` is only printed after `1` is entered into the console.

If i am running the same program directly on the cmd.exe ,the program works as intended.

This is caused by a bug in eclipse console itself.

The bug can be resolved either by calling `fflush()`after every printf

or

by adding the following line of code after main()

```
void main()
{
    setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);      // required by eclipse cdt to properly-
    setvbuf(stderr,NULL,_IONBF,0);      //-display output in console window
}
```

I have tried the second option and it works perfectly fine.

Details of the bug can be found here

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Eclipse_console_does_not_show_output_on_Windows

and here

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help...
Right click on the folder(file) you need, and click on Show in local terminal:

[image: Right click on the folder(file) you need, and click on Show in local terminal]

The local terminal will be appeared
[image: The local terminal will be appeared]